# Lazy Properties in IEnumerable

Tags: .net, vb.net, lazy-loading, ienumerable

Firstly apologies if this should be at code review rather than here. I figured here as I’m only showing pseudo code.

I have an object which is loaded from a database which in turn has a lazy loaded property which it grabs from the database.

```
Public Class Item

    Public Sub New(pRow as Datarow)
        Me.ID = CLng(pRow.Item(“ID”))
        ‘ Fill other properties from datarow
    End Sub

    Private _Tags as List(Of Tag)

    Public Readonly Property ID as Long = 0

    Public Readonly Property Tags as List(Of Tag)
      Get
        If _Tags Is Nothing Then _Tags = LoadTagsFromDB(Me.ID)
      End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Now this is great, it allows me to load an instance of an object. Use its properties, and if I require the tags I can grab them hitting the DB once.

This issue occurs when I have an `Ienumerable(Of Item)`

In some circumstances my collection size can be well in excess of 50,000+

This obviously means then when I grab the collection then iterate it I hammer the database excessively when accessing the Tags Property on each instance of item.

I’ve reworked the code in the following way.

```
Public Class Item

    Public Sub New(pRow as Datarow)
        Me.ID = CLng(pRow.Item(“ID”))
        ‘ Fill other properties from datarow
    End Sub

    Public Readonly Property ID as Long = 0

    Public Readonly Property Tags as List(Of Tags) = Nothing

    Public Sub SetTags(pDictionary as Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of Tag))
      If pDictionary.ContainsKey(Me.ID) Then
        _Tags = pDictionary.Item(Me.ID)
      Else
        _Tags = New List(Of Tag)
      End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This then allows me to do the following.

```
‘ Grab the unique ids from the collection 
Dims ids = ListOfItems.Select(function(x) x.ID).Distinct

‘ One query, giant result set.
Dim d = SQLToGetAllTagsWithIDs(IDs)

For Each o As Item in ListOfItems
  o.SetTags(d)
Next
```

This is perfect and almost infinitely quicker however when using a single instance of Item or when not calling `.SetTags` the `.Tags` property is nothing

I’ve mixed and matched both scenarios so that if it isn’t called it will instead fallback and get it via the mechanism in the first instance, however this leads me right back to the first scenario whereby other developers will just allow the lazy mechanism not realising the SetTags exists or it’s purpose.

I guess my question is, is there some model or preferred way of doing what I am trying to do that I am unaware of whereby I can achieve the best of both worlds? I’m struggling to google the question as it’s quite difficult to explain.

Hope this makes sense, hope there is a solution, if not I guess I’ll stick with what I have.

Comment: A need for a collection of `Item` is indicated. However, is it mandated that the consumer can create `Item` directly? If not, consider only exposing a `ItemCollection` type.  ItemCollection would handle new `Item` object creation and its `Tags` property would call method on `ItemCollection` to load the `Tags` if needed.  `ItemCollection` would maintain a call count and when a threshold value is reached, all unfilled `Item` objects would be populated. This would be a bit of work to setup as `ItemCollection` would need to implement `IList(of Item)`, but it would prevent most abuse cases.

Comment: Unfortunatly there is a requirement to also have it possible to have just one instance of the item too. In fact in most cases it is one, however on a few pages I show the user the complete list of items.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the logic while hiding the mechanics inside the class using static members. Using the static object makes each Item aware of other Items, allowing the logic to be moved inside the Item class.

```
Public Class Item

    Private Shared ReadOnly tagDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of Tag))()
    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Long

    Public Sub New(row As DataRow)
        Me.ID = CLng(row.Item("ID"))
        If Not tagDictionary.ContainsKey(Me.ID) Then tagDictionary.Add(Me.ID, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Tags As List(Of Tag)
        Get
            Dim emptyTagIDs = tagDictionary.Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Value Is Nothing).Select(Function(kvp) kvp.Key)
            If emptyTagIDs.Contains(Me.ID) Then
                Dim d = getAllTagsWithIDs(emptyTagIDs)
                For Each kvp In d
                    tagDictionary(kvp.Key) = kvp.Value
                Next
            End If
            Return tagDictionary(Me.ID)
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Shared Function getAllTagsWithIDs(ids As IEnumerable(Of Long)) As Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of Tag))
        ' One query, giant result set
    End Function

End Class
```

Here is how you could test it (replace with your specific implementation)

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim row As DataRow
row = dt.NewRow()
row("ID") = 1
Dim i1 = New Item(row)
row = dt.NewRow()
row("ID") = 2
Dim i2 = New Item(row)
row = dt.NewRow()
row("ID") = 3
Dim i3 = New Item(row)
Dim tags2 = i2.Tags ' at this point, all IDs are queried
row = dt.NewRow()
row("ID") = 4
Dim i4 = New Item(row)
Dim tags1 = i1.Tags ' no new query is performed because 1 was already queried
Dim tags4 = i4.Tags ' query is performed again on on new (ID = 4) items
```

The advantage is that whenever Tags is accessed, all IDs which were not previously queried are queried again, as long as the current tag was not previously queried. I think that this will work exactly as you are currently using it (I guess you have constructed all Items before querying any Tags). But it also gives you some additional flexibility to create more Items and only query the new Tags later.

Comment: I quite like that abstracting it away to the object logic makes a lot of sense as even if another developer calls it it will still do as intended. Best of both worlds. My concern (my fault for not mentioning it) is that the items and tags in question are on a multi tennanted website so the shared list could very quickly become out dated if other users were making changes at the same time. i.e. User shows list page, another user makes changes, 20 minutes later initial user refreshes. Would this then not keep original values as they are already in the shared instance?

Comment: I could clear the list per request but obviously that then requires remembering and would again leave me back at square one.

Comment: When the other user makes a change, you can invalidate the changed item by setting its dictionary value to *Nothing*, which would cause it to be queried again the next time it is accessed.